# Extension of a linear functional

Tags: reference-request

On my textbook (Frigyes Riesz, Bela Sz.-Nagy, functional analysis) there is the following theorem.

**Theorem.** A necessary and sufficient condition that the functional A, given in a set E of the space C, be extendable to the entire space C so as to define there a linear functional of norm $\leq M$ is that
$$\left|\sum_{1}^n c_k A f_k\right|\leq M \left|\left|\sum_{1}^n c_k f_k\right|\right|$$
for every linear combination of elements of E.

The theorem's proof is not very clear for me. Is there any good reference (online, if possible)?

Thanks!

Comment: Continuous means bounded, which is the condition. Then Hahn Banach gives the extension. If it's unbounded, you cannot get an extension which is.

Comment: The inequality just ensures that $A$ can be extended to a linear functional on $\operatorname{span} E$ with norm $\leqslant M$. The remaining part is the Hahn-Banach extension theorem.

Comment: Thank you. You can give me a good reference for it?